# Writing jQuery Plugins using OOP

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering what's the current "**state-of-the-art"** to write a jQuery Plugins. 
I read a lot of different approaches and I don't know which one fits best.

**Can you recommondation usefull links/templates for writing jQuery Plugins using OOP.**

Thanks

Comment: How about the official docs? http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: The docs seems not to bee best-practive, do they?

Answer (score 7):

the basic rules are:

1. Don't clutter the jQuery namespace with your code - there should
   only be one method per plugin added to root of the jQuery object or
   to `jQuery.fn`
2. Use an immediately executing anonymous funciton to ensure the code
   is run just once
3. Pass in the jQuery object as a parameter with the identifier `$`,
   can safely use the `$` in this scope then :)
4. **REMEMBER** when you add a new method to `jQuery.fn`, `this` is
   bound to a jQuery wrapped set, *you don't have to wrap it again*!
5. use `this.each` to loop through all matched elements
6. return `this` from your plugin to enable chainability (unless of course your plugin returns a distinct value)
7. allow options to be passed in and overlayed over some default object (which you also expose to be overriden)
8. allow for defaults to be re-set by user for global changes

   ```
   (function($) { //see point 3

       var defaults = {
          someDefaultValues : "value"
       };

       $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) { // see point 1, only 1 method

          var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options); //see point 7

           this.each(function() { //see point 5

              var currentElement = $(this); //"this" now refers to current DOM element
              //put bulk of logic here

           });

           return this; //see point 6
       };
       //see point 8, enables users to completely override defaults, rather than per call via options
       $.fn.myPlugin.defaults = defaults; 

   })(jQuery); //see point 2
   ```

see the jQuery docs for a [good guide](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring), they go into more advanced details considering how you might want to execute more than one method per plugin, plus storing data on elements and other things. Most of the stuff i have

Comment: +1 good advice.  Also, use a semi-colon to end the function expression of $.fn.myPlugin

Comment: Thank, but what do you think of this approach?http://jamietalbot.com/2010/08/22/object-oriented-jquery-plugins/ (and linked new versions)

Comment: oops, typo, i'm usually religious about semi-colons :) will edit and update

Comment: @fabian it looks OK, though that would definitely be convoluted and overkill for 95% of the time that you might wish to write a plugin. Also, consider how the official jQuery docs support a multi-method approach, less boilerplate and less battling with the framework. Also he's sacrificing chainability which is one of the great things about jQuery

Answer (score 3):

Two links/templates I refer to are [Stefan Gabos jQuery Plugin Boilerplate](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-revisited/) and Oscar [Godson's jQuery Plugin Skeleton](https://github.com/OscarGodson/jQuery-Plugin-Skeleton)

I'm not claiming they're "state of the art" but they've served me very well.

Comment: What about encapsulatedPlugin? http://jamietalbot.com/2010/08/22/object-oriented-jquery-plugins/

Comment: Glad you like my plugin!